# spring mvc validation with multiple field dependencies

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

We have the following vaidations which we are looking to implement

1. When "hasCancelOrSaveClicked" is "yes" we need to validate few set of fields like (title,lastname) and other fields like
   (countryOfBirth,hasCountryOfTaxResidence,countryOfTaxResidence) in
   the form should not be validated or their validation should be
   skipped
2. When "hasCancelOrSaveClicked" is "no" all the fields should be validated. But we are facing issues with conditional
   groups when we have interdependencies between fields like
   "countryOfTaxResidence" is dependent on value of
   "hasCountryOfTaxResidence" and "hasCancelOrSaveClicked" is "no"

   Please let us know if there is a way to handle this kind of complex validations in spring?

{

```
   @ValidCountryOfTaxContribution
    @ConditionalGroup.List({
        @ConditionalGroup(dependentOnField = "hasCountryOfTaxResidence", value = { "yes" }, groupsToRun = { CountryOfTaxResidence.class }),
        @ConditionalGroup(dependentOnField = "hasCountryOfTaxContribution", value = { "yes" }, groupsToRun = { CountryOfTaxContribution.class }),
        @ConditionalGroup(dependentOnField = "countryOfTaxResidence", value={""}, groupsToRun={HasCountryOfTaxResidence.class}, inverse=true),
        @ConditionalGroup(dependentOnField = "countryOfTaxContribution", value={""}, groupsToRun={HasCountryOfTaxContribution.class}, inverse=true),
        @ConditionalGroup(dependentOnField = "hasCancelOrSaveClicked", value = { "no" }, groupsToRun = { HasCancelOrSaveClicked.class }),

    })
    @CancelConditionalGroup.List({
        @CancelConditionalGroup(dependentOnField = "hasCancelOrSaveClicked,title", value = { "" }, groupsToRun = { CancelLastName.class,CancelTitle.class,OtherTitle.class }),
    })

    public class PersonalInformationFormData extends BaseFormData {

        interface OtherTitle {};
        interface CancelClicked {};
        interface CancelLastName {};
        interface CancelTitle{};

        interface HasCancelOrSaveClicked {};    
        interface CountryOfTaxResidence {};
        interface CountryOfTaxContribution {};
        interface HasCountryOfTaxResidence {};
        interface HasCountryOfTaxContribution {};

        @NotEmpty(groups = {CancelTitle.class })
        private String title;

        @NotEmpty
        private String dependent;

        @NotEmpty(groups = {OtherTitle.class }, message="Please select your title from the options provided. If you can't see your title please select other and choose from the extended list")
        private String otherTitle;

        @NotEmpty(groups = {CancelLastName.class })
        @Size(max = 50)
        private String lastName;

        @NotEmpty(groups = {HasCancelOrSaveClicked.class })
        private String countryOfBirth;

        @NotEmpty(groups = {HasCancelOrSaveClicked.class })
        private String hasCountryOfTaxResidence;

        @NotEmpty(groups = { CountryOfTaxResidence.class }, message="Please select country of tax residence from the list provided")
        private String countryOfTaxResidence;

        private String taxResidenceTin;

        @NotEmpty(groups = {CountryOfTaxResidence.class}, message="Please select if you have any additional Country Of Tax Residence")
        private String hasCountryOfTaxContribution; 

        @NotEmpty(groups = { CountryOfTaxContribution.class }, message="Please select country of tax contribution")
        private String countryOfTaxContribution;

        private boolean isCountryOfTaxResidence;

        private String hasCancelOrSaveClicked;  

    }
```

}

Comment: _"But we are facing issues"_ What are those issues?

Comment: Is there anyway to change group classes that can be applied based on the field inputs?